Is a custom table added to MS Business Central automatically available in the API (2.0)?
If I want to update a sales invoice, I can use the build in API (2.0) in Business Central.
Here is described how:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/api/dynamics_salesinvoice_update
But this works with the build in tables. Can I do the same thing with a table I created myself? I mean, will the same API methods automatically be available?
And if not, what would be the best way create a public REST API / webservice available to be able to update my table?
I am quite new to BC so any explanation, advice, example is welcome. Thanks

Yes, you can do the same thing with your custom table, however it doesn't happen automatically.
You need to create an API Page with your table as the source table.
Once the API Page is included in your extension it will be automatically published as an API when the extension is installed thus enabling the same features for integration as are available for the standard API's i.e., Power Automate, Power BI etc.
Check out the walkthrough on Microsoft Learn to learn how to develop your own custom API.
